# android how put .ini file near SO libs

Tags: android, native

How I can put my .ini file in the folder where my SO libs are? Native code use this .ini from ApplicationPath

Answer (score 0):

> How I can put my .ini file in the folder where my SO libs are?

AFAIK, you can't.

> Native code use this .ini from ApplicationPath

Please rewrite the native code to be less embarrassing, by having it take a path as a parameter to a JNI function.

Comment: Thank you, I also think it will be the better way